# How to call "public void" method through rJava

Tags: r, rjava

In testing a Java API, I need to change a default setting. According to the API's document, it should be done using a method defined within the class using "public void setType". Suppose the class name is 'Node', which is referred using

```
library(rJava) 
.jinit(classpath=jarPath)
Node <- J("Node")
```

In an Java example from its documents, it's called as

```
 Node nodeX = new Node("X", new Variable[]{x});
 nodeX.setType(Type.TEMP);
```

The default type of nodeX is 'CONTEMP'. How the "setType" method can be called in R through rJava to change its default value to another one? Let's assume 'Type' is an enum variable which has several options, including "CONTEMP","TEMP", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
library(rJava) 
.jinit(classpath=jarPath)
variable <- .jarray(new(J("package.name.Variable", input_arg))
Node <- new(J("package.name.Node"), variable)
```

Then you can do

```
type <- J("package.name.Type")$TEMP
Node$setType(type)
```

Comment: It gives me "no static field, method or inner class called `TEMP' in `model.Node' " ('model' is the package.name).

Comment: From your question I thought the enum was `Type` with desired value `TEMP`. That line is about getting the correct enum value so that you can pass it into the `setType` method. Your comment indicates that you are trying to pull the enum value out of the `Node` class.

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much